# retrieving boolean values from fireabase database with react js and display the value

Tags: reactjs, firebase-realtime-database

this is the pushing to DB code which works fine

```
 pushtoDB = () => {
    var ref = fire.database().ref("data");
    var newRef = ref.push();
    const rookie = this.props.userLevel1;
    const student = this.props.userLevel2;
    const intermediate = this.props.userLevel3 ? "intermediate" : null;
    const expert = this.props.userLevel4 ? "expert" : null;
    const master = this.props.userLevel5 ? "master" : null;

    newRef.set({
      ID: fire.auth().currentUser.uid,
      UserEmail: fire.auth().currentUser.email,
      Question: this.state.questions, //Send data to DB to track for analysis
      UserAnswer: this.state.userAns,
      Score: this.state.scores,
      UserLevel: rookie
      //  UserLevel: student
      // UserLevel: intermediate,
      // UserLevel: expert,
      //UserLevel: master
    });

    console.log("Sent to Database");
  };
```

here in the DB i can see value for Userlevel is "true" which is what i want

I want to display the true value as "rookie" in using this code..it looks right but its displaying "no data"

```
 return (
      <div id="container" style={{ fontFamily: "sans-serif" }}>
        <Card border="primary" style={{ width: "40rem", marginLeft: 50 }}>
          <Card.Header style={{ textAlign: "center" }}> Profile</Card.Header>
          <Card.Body>
            <Card.Title style={{ marginLeft: 230 }}>
              <img id="profilepic" src={ProfilePic} />
            </Card.Title>
            <Card.Text style={{ marginLeft: 70 }}>
              <br></br>
              <ul>
                <MdEmail /> Email :
                {this.props.email ? this.props.email : "No data for Email"}
                <br></br>
                Score :
                {this.props.score ? this.props.score : "No data for Score"}
                <br></br>
                Level : {this.props.level ? "rookie" : "no data"}
              </ul>
            </Card.Text>
          </Card.Body>
        </Card>
      </div>
```

any help would be great thanks

Answer (score 0):

`rookie` is just a local variable inside the `pushtoDB` method, and is not available in your `render` implementation.

You can either check the `userLevel1` property in your rendering code:

```
return (
      <div id="container" style={{ fontFamily: "sans-serif" }}>
        <Card border="primary" style={{ width: "40rem", marginLeft: 50 }}>
          <Card.Header style={{ textAlign: "center" }}> Profile</Card.Header>
          <Card.Body>
            <Card.Title style={{ marginLeft: 230 }}>
              <img id="profilepic" src={ProfilePic} />
            </Card.Title>
            <Card.Text style={{ marginLeft: 70 }}>
              <br></br>
              <ul>
                <MdEmail /> Email :
                {this.props.email ? this.props.email : "No data for Email"}
                <br></br>
                Score :
                {this.props.score ? this.props.score : "No data for Score"}
                <br></br>
                Level : {this.props.userLevel1 ? "rookie" : "no data"}
              </ul>
            </Card.Text>
          </Card.Body>
        </Card>
      </div>
```

Alternatively, you can set the `rookie` value in the state, and then use *that* in your rendering code:

```
pushtoDB = () => {
    var ref = fire.database().ref("data");
    var newRef = ref.push();
    const rookie = this.props.userLevel1;
    const student = this.props.userLevel2;
    const intermediate = this.props.userLevel3 ? "intermediate" : null;
    const expert = this.props.userLevel4 ? "expert" : null;
    const master = this.props.userLevel5 ? "master" : null;

    this.setState({ level: rookie });

    ...
}
...
                Level : {this.state.level ? "rookie" : "no data"}
```

Comment: but i m sending that value as prop to another component how do i do that check

Comment: im only using the rookie to push data to DB only

Comment: i want to retrive that data (boolean value) in the database and display it using props

Comment: see above comments

Comment: The second code snippet in my answer shows how to set the calculated value to the `state` of your component, and then use it in your rendering.

Comment: but that way u have there it doesnt sent data to DB i want it to retieve it from DB and display via props

Comment: In that case you need to attach an `on()` or `once()` listener to the database, and call `setState` when that data comes back.